# How to present a new custom NSView (modally?)

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, modalviewcontroller

I'm working on my first Cocoa app being an iOS Developer. So far I found most of the information I needed online but I'm having trouble to figure out how to show a new custom NSView / NSWindow (not sure which) as show below:

A push in the right direction is more than welcome..

[image: modal]

Comment: Do you want to display a custom view or use an `NSSavePanel` (which is what appears in your animated gif)?

Comment: Right now I have a NSView (custom) ready to be shown but I don't know how to do this

Comment: You need to create an `NSWindowController`, which can be done in IB and loaded as a NIB and then displayed modally.  There are many examples on the net and Apple's own guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/UsingModalWindows.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NSPanel with custom view and call

```
NSPanel *panel=[[NSPanel alloc]initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 800, 530) styleMask:NSClosableWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
panel.contentView=<# your custom view #>

[self.view.window beginSheet: panel completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {}];
```

Comment: And how to do I set the custom view? NSPanel has no property to set this

Comment: Just found it after going through all the properties, it works, thanks a lot!